# C how to get argument of type pointer to function from va_arg

Tags: c

I know that if I passed an argument like `void (*func)(void *)` to a variadic function, I can retrieve the argument like:

```
void (*func)(void *) = va_arg( args, void (*)(void) );
```

What if I pass something like `void (** func)(void *)`? What is the correct syntax to retrieve an argument of this type using `va_arg`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Being frankly, your code is not standard-compliant. There is a tiny restriction for second argument of [`va_arg()`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.16.1.1) macro:

> ... The parameter `type` shall be a type name specified such that the type
>   of a pointer to an object that has the specified type can be obtained
>   simply by postfixing a * to type. ...

According to this, notation like `void (*)(void *)` is unacceptable in this case. Since simple appending of `*` won't give you pointer to pointer to function. You may use only `typedef`-ed aliases:

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(void *);
typedef void (**ptr_to_func_ptr)(void *);

func_ptr var1 = va_arg(ap, func_ptr);
ptr_to_func_ptr var2 = va_arg(ap, ptr_to_func_ptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Same as you've mentioned:

```
typedef void (** func_t)(void *);
func_t ppf;
va_list vl;
va_start(vl,n);
ppf = va_arg(vl, func_t);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

To help pointer-to-function, I *always* use `typedef` as follows:

```
typedef void VoidFn(void *); // Function accepts void * and returns nothing.
```

That declares the prototype of the function as a `typedef`, allowing the use of the `typedef` elsewhere.

That way if you have this function:

```
void SomeFn(void *) {...}
```

you can declare this pointer:

```
VoidFn *fnPtr = &SomeFn; // A pointer to such a function.
```

This then makes it easier to change the prototype *independently* of the pointer, helping more... sophisticated constructs:

```
typedef void *VoidPtrFn(void *); // Function takes a void *, returning a void *

void *SomeOtherFn(void *) { ... }
VoidPtrFn *otherFnPtr = &SomeOtherFn;
VoidPtrFn **otherFnPtrPtr = &otherFnPtr;
```